# nuget restore failing in team services build

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-pipelines, nuget-package-restore

I have 2 local assemblies referenced via nuget (packed the dll's up) using vs2017 on a asp.net core solution, builds fine locally.

Now trying to generate a build via VSTS i am getting the following error,

```
Detected NuGet version 4.0.0.2283 / 4.0.0
SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
Saving NuGet.config to a temporary config file.
d:\a\_tool\NuGet\4.0.0\x64\nuget.exe restore d:\a\1\s\TestFrameworkCoreAPI.sln -Verbosity Detailed -NonInteractive -ConfigFile d:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_37.config
NuGet Version: 4.0.0.2283
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.3.409.57025' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\bin'. Use option -MSBuildVersion to force nuget to use a specific version of MSBuild.
MSBuild P2P timeout [ms]: 120000
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\bin\msbuild.exe /t:GenerateRestoreGraphFile /nologo /nr:false /p:RestoreUseCustomAfterTargets=true /p:BuildProjectReferences=false /v:q  /p:NuGetRestoreTargets="d:\a\_temp\NuGet-Scratch\w53qa5rr.4sd.targets" /p:RestoreTaskAssemblyFile="d:\a\_tool\NuGet\4.0.0\x64\nuget.exe" /p:RestoreGraphOutputPath="d:\a\_temp\NuGet-Scratch\4mlmlfgh.mmy.result" /p:ExcludeRestorePackageImports=true  /p:RestoreRecursive=False  /p:RestoreProjectFilterMode=exclusionlist /p:RestoreContinueOnError=WarnAndContinue  /p:RestoreGraphProjectInput="d:\a\1\s\TestFrameworkCoreAPI\TestFrameworkCoreAPI.csproj;" "d:\a\_temp\NuGet-Scratch\w53qa5rr.4sd.targets"
Running restore with 2 concurrent jobs.
Reading project file d:\a\1\s\TestFrameworkCoreAPI\TestFrameworkCoreAPI.csproj.
Reading project file d:\a\1\s\TestFrameworkCoreAPI\TestFrameworkCoreAPI.csproj.
Restoring packages for d:\a\1\s\TestFrameworkCoreAPI\TestFrameworkCoreAPI.csproj...
Restoring packages for d:\a\1\s\TestFrameworkCoreAPI\TestFrameworkCoreAPI.csproj...
Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1...
Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0...
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException: Failed to retrieve information about 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools' from remote source 'D:\TestFrameworkAssemblies'.
   at NuGet.Protocol.LocalV3FindPackageByIdResource.GetVersionsCore(String id, ILogger logger)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at NuGet.Protocol.LocalV3FindPackageByIdResource.GetAllVersionsAsync(String id, SourceCacheContext cacheContext, ILogger logger, CancellationToken token)
   at NuGet.Commands.SourceRepositoryDependencyProvider.<FindLibraryAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
Error: d:\a\_tool\NuGet\4.0.0\x64\nuget.exe failed with return code: 1
Packages failed to restore
```

I have a nuget.config file in a .nuget folder located in the root of solution,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<packageSources>
  <!-- remove any machine-wide sources with <clear/> -->
  <clear />
  <add key="Test Framework" value="D:\TestFrameworkAssemblies" />
  <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
</packageSources>
<activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
</activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

This is what is in the VSTS build def, NuGet restore step

[image: build definition]

It looks like it always references my local assembly and not the standard nuget.org, now in the config file, if i take out my local entry to framework assemblies, the nuget part works but i get a primary reference error as it cannot find the 2 assemblies i have packed locally.

Been going round in circles with this at the moment, how can you get VSTS to restore local packed assemblies as well as from nuget.org.  I am using Hosted 2017 as well.

thanks in advance

Comment: Are the packages located in `D:\TestFrameworkAssemblies` *on the build server*?

Comment: doing the build using VSTS so online, can you access the file system on a hosted agent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you were queue the build on Hosted agent. Since there has the packages located on your local machine, you should **build with the [private agent](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows) which located on your local machine**.

Additional, if you need to queue the build on Hosted agent, you should add the local packages in repository, and then reference the packages with the new path and change the value in `nuget.config`.

Comment: So i have to add the packages to my solution held in VSTS, then somehow reference ?.  Do you have an example.  In my solution i already reference the local path but trying to setup VSTS CI/CD on this solution, seems like it is a lot more complicated as all i am doing is trying to reference 2 local assemblies which would be the norm in development.

Comment: How do you build with private agent via VSTS ?

Comment: You need to setup a private agent first, detail steps as https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows.

Comment: we have progress :-), done the build agent now does the nuget restore fine so will set your reply as the answer.  Have another error though when it builds solution

Comment: The "TransformWebConfig" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.1.0\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\..\..\tools\net46\\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.1.0\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\tools\net46\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.Tasks.dll' or one of its dependencies.Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

Comment: Got it working by following this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/04/25/automatically-build-and-deploy-asp-net-core-projects-to-azure-app-services/) - but had to use Private Agent as answer suggested.  Think these errors are due to the fact i am using MSBuild framework versions when it should be Core tasks